# Upgrade to 22.04 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) failed

Tags: upgrade

During the upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04, installation stopped for taking a decision for, I think, samba configuration. I selected the last option to open a shell and compare the 2 configurations, new and old.
Here the upgrade stopped and after about 10 minutes of waiting I tried to reboot the system, but it doesn't come up any more.
Ubuntu was installed together with windows on dual boot.
How can I resume the installation and if not, what can be done?

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't come up"? and stopping an install/upgrade in the middle is a great way to damage your system. If you can boot and run `upgrade` again, then do that. Otherwise you may need to re-install (if you reinstall without formatting you should still have all of your personal files)

Comment: "does not come up" means that after reboot nothing happens, it does not boot.
So, if it does not boot, how can I re-install it?